# Auto-commit to Subversion using bash script

Tags: svn, bash

I have the following bash script, which is run every 15 minutes by cron.  The idea is that it will add any new files to the repo, then commit all changes:

```
#! /bin/sh

# Add any new files found in /wc
svn add /wc --force

# Commit all changes to repository
svn commit /wc -m "Auto commit"
```

The svn add command is throwing an error:

```
svn: '/' is not a working copy
```

What am I doing wrong?

Running `svn add /wc --force` from command line throws the same error.

Comment: It should work, if `/wc` is a working copy. It is, isn't it?

Comment: Yes - wc stands for working copy.

Comment: Yeah, and, what does `svn info /wc` print?

Answer (score 2):

as I tested a second ago, that should work:

```
svn add --depth=infinity --force /wc/*
```

I assume /wc is your working copy of the svn repo.

edit:
actually you just need to add /* probably, I think -depth=infinity is set by default.

Answer (score 1):

Change into the directory (inside the bash script) before running the SVN commands, just with a

```
cd /wc
```

inside your script.

Comment: Why would you need this if you provide absolute paths? How will it help?

Comment: It does work, as you changed the working directory on which the command is run, but I don't understand why using an absolute path doesn't work either!